# can not get the changed attribute using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I fetched the data from remote sever, and appended different rows to the table, now, I want to get all the checked box data and do further treatment, like when tick the box, then the data will be pushed to an array, and remove the element from that array when tick off the check box. so now, the question is, i can not select the checked box which the attribute was changed after appending work, the core code part is:

```
$row.find('input[ischecked="unchecked"]').on('click', function(){
        $(this).attr('ischecked','checked'); // it works here
            if($.inArray(this.value, tickedArray) === -1){
                tickedArray.push(this.value);
            }
             console.log('checked');
            });
            // it can not get the ischecked="checked"
            $row.find('input[ischecked="checked"]').on('click', function(){
                console.log('unchecked');
            });
```

and the full code here:

```
  $(function(){
            var url = some url;
            var tickedArray = [];
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type:'GET',
                xhrFields: {
                    withCredentials: true,
                },
                success:function(data){
                    $.each(data.stories, function(index, value){
                        var $row = $("<tr>" +
                            "<td><input type='checkbox' value="+ value.id +" ischecked='unchecked'></td>" +
                            "<td>" + value.title + "</td>"+
                            "<td>" + value.author_name + "</td>"+
                            "<td>" + value.likes + "</td>"+
                            "<td>" + value.created + "</td>"+
                            "</tr>");
                        $row.find('input[ischecked="unchecked"]').on('click', function(){
                            $(this).attr('ischecked','checked');
                            if($.inArray(this.value, tickedArray) === -1){
                                tickedArray.push(this.value);
                            }
                            console.log('checked');
                        });
                        $row.find('input[ischecked="checked"]').on('click', function(){
                            console.log('unchecked');
                        });
                        $('#stories_list_table > tbody:last').
                        append($row);
                    });
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: Have you tried using `attr('checked')` to get your checkbox's value rather than `ischecked`?

Comment: I think it's better to select like that:
`$row.on('click', 'input[ischecked="unchecked"]', function(){});`

Comment: @SirCelsius yep, i have tried, I can get the "checked" data and also can modify the value of the attribute, but the key problem was I can not get the modified attribute element.

Comment: `ischecked` is not a valid attribute, what was wrong with the valid `checked` attribute? Cos then instead of ugly selector like `input[ischecked="unchecked"]` you can simple use `input:not(:checked)`

Comment: @gillesc thx for your reply, i've tried even without any attr, like "<td><input type='checkbox' value="+ value.id +"></td>", but the problem was, I can not select the unchecked element, when I try to input:not(:checked), I can not get the dom element.. it's pretty annoying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$row.find('input[ischecked="checked"]').on('click', function(){
    console.log('unchecked');
});
```

This selector won't find any checkbox because there aren't any at *that* moment. Instead of creating 2 `click` events you should only create 1 `change` event and check the `ischecked` attribute for it's value.

Also, why do you create your own `ischecked` attribute instead of using the standard `checked` property?

Comment: thx for your reply, i just remove the custom ischecked attr, and also create only one change event like: $row.find('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function(){console.log(this);}); 
but the console gave me two same output,like:
<input type="checkbox" value="id123456">
<input type="checkbox" value="id123456">
without any checked attr added, why?

Comment: Use `$(this).prop("checked")` to get a true/false value. Don't use `attr` for this - It's a weird jQuery thing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try using event delegation, like this :

```
$row.on('click', 'input[ischecked="checked"]', function(){
     console.log('unchecked');
});
```

Comment: thx for your reply, i' ve tried like this 
$row.on('click', 'input[ischecked="unchecked"]', function(){
console.log('checked');
});
     $row.on('click', 'input[ischecked="checked"]', function(){
          console.log('unchecked');
     });
but the console gave me double checked.. no unchecked showed.